How to Display a Back Button in the Header When Navigating to Nested Screens in a React Native Expo Drawer Layout?
I'm struggling to figure out how to automatically show the back button in the header when navigating to a nested screen in a Drawer layout using expo-router/drawer. I know this works with a Stack layout, but I don't know how to achieve the same behavior with a Drawer.
Folder Structure:
 app/
 |-- (app)/
 |   |-- dashboard/
 |   |   |-- detail/
 |   |   |   `-- index.jsx
 |   |   `-- index.jsx
 |   |-- _layout.jsx
 |   `-- index.jsx
 |-- _layout.jsx
 `-- sign-in.jsx

Code:
Root layout:
export default function App() {
  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="sign-in"
          options={{
            title: 'Sign In',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="(app)"
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      </Stack>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

(app) _layout.jsx:
function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent drawerData={appDrawerNavData} {...props} />}
      backBehavior="history"
      screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          width: 342,
        },
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="dashboard/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Dashboard',
        }}
      />
    </Drawer>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const { session, isLoading } = useSession();
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  if (!session) {
    return <Redirect href="/sign-in" />;
  }

  return <DrawerNavigator />;
}

Problem:
When I navigate to the dashboard/detail screen, I still see a drawer icon in the header instead of the back icon.
Question:
What am I doing wrong here? How can I ensure that the back button automatically appears when navigating to nested screens in the Drawer layout?
Thanks in advance for your help!
What I Tried:
I set up a Drawer layout in my Expo React Native app, expecting it to automatically show the back button in the header when navigating to nested screens, similar to how it works in a Stack layout. My Drawer configuration includes a custom drawer content component, and I set backBehavior to "history" hoping this would trigger the back button to appear.
What I Expected:
I expected that when navigating from the dashboard screen to the detail screen, the header would automatically update to show a back button, allowing users to navigate back to the dashboard screen.

I somehow managed to resolve the issue.
What I did end up doing was adding a stack layout in the dashboard folder.
Folder structure
  app/
 |-- (app)/
 |   |-- dashboard/
 |   |   |-- detail/
 |   |   |   `-- index.jsx
 |   |   `-- index.jsx
 |   |   `-- _layout.jsx // Dashboard Stack Navigator
 |   |-- _layout.jsx // Drawer Navigator
 |   `-- index.jsx
 |-- _layout.jsx  // Root Stack Navigator
 `-- sign-in.jsx

Dashboard _layout
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function DashboardStack() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: 'Dashboard',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="detail/index"
        options={{
          title: 'Detail',
          // The back button is automatically handled by Stack Navigator
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );

